# Calling non-static method from within mousehandler results in error:" non static method cannot be referenced from static context

Tags: java, static, mouse-listeners

As the title states im having trouble with a method inside a mousehandler. My mousehandler is:

```
public class MouseHandler implements MouseListener{

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){


    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            try {
                Pieces.getPos(e, coordinateXYZV, tile,chessBoard);
            }catch (Exception a){

            }
        }
    }
```

now i know questions about static stuff are really not welcome, but i just cant seem to find the solution although similar problems were easily fixed. Neither the class with the mousehandler nor the method is static, so why am i getting this error in the first place?
Im creating a new mousehandler like this:

```
MouseHandler mhandler = new MouseHandler();
```

and then pass it around to whereever its needed. if anything further is needed please point it out because this is my first time asking a question here and im not entirely sure whats needed to help me here

Comment: `Pieces.getPos` is `Pieces` a class or a badly named instance of something? Is `getPos` a static method?

Comment: "i know questions about static stuff are really not welcome" uh? What do you mean?

Comment: Yes, Pieces is a class with getPos as a method, both of which are not static.

"i know questions about static stuff are really not welcome" most threads i´ve read related to this result in downvotes or ppl are just told to search for it, so i figured this was smth which i should be able to solve myself by just looking it up here

Comment: If `Pieces` is a class and `getPos` is a non-static method... well, you have your answer. You're calling a non-static method on a class instead of an instance of `Pieces`. Not knowing what `Pieces` is and how it's expected to be instantiated, that's all we can say to help you.

Comment: @speedprogrammer9000 That means you are attempting to call a non-static method with the class `Pieces`, when you should be using a `Pieces` object that you create with `Pieces p = new Pieces(...)` and then call the method with `p.getPieces(...)`, or something along those lines.

Comment: is Pieces a static class? if it isn't"t you're calling getPos wrong

Comment: well that was all i needed to read to spot my mistake in seconds. thank u very much :)

Answer (score 1):

For future people stumbling upon this: call your methods correclty:

```
 @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            try {
                Pieces p = new Pieces();                       <--
                p.getPos(e, coordinateXYZV, tile,chessBoard);  <--
            }catch (Exception a){

            }
        }
    }
```